# Blending anti-aliased circles with regl

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, blending, regl

I'm rendering circles using regl, and have three goals:

1. The canvas should be transparent, showing HTML content behind it.
2. Circles should be antialiased smoothly.
3. Overlapping circles should look reasonable (blend colors, no corners showing)

So far, I have this: Glitch [code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/regl-point-blending) and [demo](https://regl-point-blending.glitch.me/).

> UPDATE: The demo links now reflect the working, accepted answer. Code below is unchanged.

**index.js**

```
const regl = require('regl');
const glsl = require('glslify');
const vertexShader = glsl.file('../shaders/vertex.glsl');
const fragmentShader = glsl.file('../shaders/fragment.glsl');

// Create webgl context and clear.
const canvasEl = document.querySelector('canvas');
const app = regl({
  canvas: canvasEl,
  extensions: ['OES_standard_derivatives']
});
app.clear({color: [0, 0, 0, 0], depth: 1});

// Generate random points and colors.
const attributes = {position: [], color: []};
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  attributes.position.push(Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1);
  attributes.color.push(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());
}

// Define draw instructions.
const draw = app({
  vert: vertexShader,
  frag: fragmentShader,
  attributes: attributes,
  count: 100,
  primitive: 'points',
  depth: {enable: true},
  blend: {
    enable: true
  }
});

// Draw the points.
draw();
```

**vertex.glsl**

```
// vertex.glsl
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec3 color;

varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {
  vColor = color;
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 40.;
}
```

**fragment.glsl**

```
// fragment.glsl
#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
#endif

precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {

  float r = 0.0, delta = 0.0, alpha = 1.0;
  vec2 cxy = 2.0 * gl_PointCoord - 1.0;
  r = dot(cxy, cxy);

#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives
  delta = fwidth(r);
  alpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(1.0 - delta, 1.0 + delta, r);
#endif

  gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, alpha);
}
```

However, the result looks not-so-great. Corners are visible, and circles aren't blending properly.

[image: circles with default blending]

I've also tried adding the following blend terms:

```
func: {
  srcRGB: 'src alpha',
  srcAlpha: 'one minus src alpha',
  dstRGB: 'one minus src alpha',
  dstAlpha: 'src alpha'
}
```

[image: circles with custom blending]

This looks a bit better, but the corners are still there and something is wrong when the background is white.

Could you suggest improvements to this? (And maybe point me to better information about blending, if that's what I'm missing here) Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set up your blending parameters like this:

```
func: {
    srcRGB:   'src alpha',
    srcAlpha: 'src alpha',
    dstRGB:   'one minus src alpha',
    dstAlpha: 'one minus src alpha'
}
```

This means that your destination and source color become blended like this:

Red, green and blue (`srcRGB: 'src alpha'`, `dstRGB: 'one minus src alpha'`):

```
R_dest = R_dest * (1 - Alpha_src) + R_src * Alpha_src
G_dest = G_dest * (1 - Alpha_src) + G_src * Alpha_src
B_dest = R_dest * (1 - Alpha_src) + R_src * Alpha_src
```

The alpha channel (`srcAlpha: 'src alpha'`, `dstAlpha: 'one minus src alpha'`):

```
Alpha_dest = Alpha_dest * (1 - Alpha_src) + Alpha_src * Alpha_src
```

seel also [glBlendFunc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml) and [glBlendFuncSeparate](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFuncSeparate.xhtml)

**Further you have to make sure that the depth test is disabled**

See the WebGL example above (tested with Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Opera):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

back_vert =
"precision mediump float; \n" +
"attribute vec2 inPos; \n" +
"varying vec2 pos; \n" +
"uniform   mat4 u_projectionMat44;" +
"uniform   mat4 u_modelViewMat44;" +
"void main()" +
"{" +
"    pos           = inPos.xy;" +
"    vec4 viewPos  = u_modelViewMat44 * vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );" +
"    gl_Position   = u_projectionMat44 * viewPos;" +
"}";

back_frag =
"precision mediump float; \n" +
"varying vec2 pos; \n" +
"void main() \n" +
"{ \n" +
"    vec2 coord = pos * 0.5 + 0.5; \n" +
"    float gray = smoothstep( 0.3, 0.7, (coord.x + coord.y) * 0.5 ); \n" +
"    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( gray ), 1.0 ); \n" +
"}";

draw_vert =
"precision mediump float; \n" +
"attribute vec2 inPos; \n" +
"varying vec2 pos; \n" +
"uniform   mat4 u_projectionMat44;" +
"uniform   mat4 u_modelViewMat44;" +
"void main()" +
"{" +
"    pos           = inPos.xy;" +
"    vec4 viewPos  = u_modelViewMat44 * vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );" +
"    gl_Position   = u_projectionMat44 * viewPos;" +
"}";

draw_frag =
"precision mediump float; \n" +
"varying vec2 pos; \n" +
"uniform vec4 u_color;" +
"uniform vec2 u_vp;" +
"void main()" +
"{" +
"    float r = length( pos );" +
"    float d = 4.0 * length( 1.0 / u_vp ); \n" +
"    float a = 1.0 - smoothstep( 1.0 - d, 1.0 + d, r ); \n" +
"    gl_FragColor = vec4( u_color.rgb, u_color.a * a );" +
"}";

glArrayType = typeof Float32Array !="undefined" ? Float32Array : ( typeof WebGLFloatArray != "undefined" ? WebGLFloatArray : Array );

function IdentityMat44() {
    var m = new glArrayType(16);
    m[0]  = 1; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  = 0; m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = 0; m[5]  = 1; m[6]  = 0; m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = 0; m[9]  = 0; m[10] = 1; m[11] = 0;
    m[12] = 0; m[13] = 0; m[14] = 0; m[15] = 1;
    return m;
};

function RotateAxis(matA, angRad, axis) {
    var aMap = [ [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 1] ];
    var a0 = aMap[axis][0], a1 = aMap[axis][1]; 
    var sinAng = Math.sin(angRad), cosAng = Math.cos(angRad);
    var matB = new glArrayType(16);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) matB[i] = matA[i];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i ) {
        matB[a0*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * cosAng + matA[a1*4+i] * sinAng;
        matB[a1*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * -sinAng + matA[a1*4+i] * cosAng;
    }
    return matB;
}

function Translate( matA, trans ) {
    var matB = new glArrayType(16);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) matB[i] = matA[i];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i )
        matB[12+i] = matA[i] * trans[0] + matA[4+i] * trans[1] + matA[8+i] * trans[2] + matA[12+i];
    return matB;
}

function Scale( matA, scale ) {
    var matB = new glArrayType(16);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) matB[i] = matA[i];
    for ( var a = 0; a < 4; ++ a )
        for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i )
            matB[a*4+i] = matA[a*4+i] * scale[0];
    return matB;
}

Ortho = function( l, r, t, b, n, f ) {
    var fn  = f + n;
    var f_n = f - n;
    var m = IdentityMat44();
    m[0]  = 2/(r-l); m[1]  = 0;       m[2]  =  0;       m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = 0;       m[5]  = 2/(t-b); m[6]  =  0;       m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = 0;       m[9]  = 0;       m[10] = -2 / f_n; m[11] = -fn / f_n;
    m[12] = 0;       m[13] = 0;       m[14] = 0;        m[15] = 1;
    return m;
}

vec4_add = function( a, b ) { return [ a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1], a[2]+b[2], a[3]+b[3] ]; }
vec4_sub = function( a, b ) { return [ a[0]-b[0], a[1]-b[1], a[2]-b[2], a[3]-b[3] ]; }
vec4_mul = function( a, b ) { return [ a[0]*b[0], a[1]*b[1], a[2]*b[2], a[3]*b[3] ]; }
vec4_scale = function( a, s ) { return [ a[0]*s, a[1]*s, a[2]*s, a[3]*s ]; }

// shader program object
var ShaderProgram = {};
ShaderProgram.Create = function( shaderList, uniformNames ) {
    var shaderObjs = [];
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++ i_sh ) {
        var shderObj = this.CompileShader( shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage );
        if ( shderObj == 0 )
          return 0;
        shaderObjs.push( shderObj );
    }
    var progObj = this.LinkProgram( shaderObjs )
    if ( progObj != 0 ) {
        progObj.unifomLocation = {};
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < uniformNames.length; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = uniformNames[i_n];
            progObj.unifomLocation[name] = gl.getUniformLocation( progObj, name );
        }
    }
    return progObj;
}
ShaderProgram.Use = function( progObj ) { gl.useProgram( progObj ); } 
ShaderProgram.SetUniformInt = function( progObj, name, val ) { gl.uniform1i( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniform2f = function( progObj, name, arr ) { gl.uniform2fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniform3f = function( progObj, name, arr ) { gl.uniform3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniform4f = function( progObj, name, arr ) { gl.uniform4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformMat44 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { gl.uniformMatrix4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.CompileShader = function( source, shaderStage ) {
    var shaderObj = gl.createShader( shaderStage );
    gl.shaderSource( shaderObj, source );
    gl.compileShader( shaderObj );
    var status = gl.getShaderParameter( shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
    return status ? shaderObj : 0;
} 
ShaderProgram.LinkProgram = function( shaderObjs ) {
    var prog = gl.createProgram();
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++ i_sh )
        gl.attachShader( prog, shaderObjs[i_sh] );
    gl.linkProgram( prog );
    status = gl.getProgramParameter( prog, gl.LINK_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    gl.useProgram( null );
    return status ? prog : 0;
}
        

function drawScene(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById( "camera-canvas" );
    var vp = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    var currentTime = Date.now();   
    var deltaMS = currentTime - startTime;
    var aspect =  canvas.width / canvas.height;
    var matOrtho = Ortho( -aspect, aspect, 1, -1, -1, 1 );
    var alpha = document.getElementById( "alpha" ).value / 100;
        
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.disable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.disable( gl.BLEND );
    ShaderProgram.Use( progBack );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformMat44( progBack, "u_projectionMat44",  matOrtho );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformMat44( progBack, "u_modelViewMat44", IdentityMat44() );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progBack.inPos );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.pos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progBack.inPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); 
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inx.len, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray( progBack.pos ); 

    gl.enable( gl.BLEND );
    gl.blendFunc( gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
    ShaderProgram.Use( progDraw );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inPos );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.pos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progDraw.inPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); 
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformMat44( progDraw, "u_projectionMat44",  matOrtho );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniform2f( progDraw, "u_vp",  vp );
        
    var col = [ [1.0,0.0,0.0], [1.0,1.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0,1.0] ];
    var time = [ 7.0, 11.0, 13.0 ];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i ) {    
        var modelMat = Scale( IdentityMat44(), [ 0.3, 0.3, 0.3] );
        var angRad = CalcAng( currentTime, time[i] ) + i * Math.PI * 2 / 3;
        var sinAng = Math.sin(angRad), cosAng = Math.cos(angRad);
        modelMat[12] = cosAng * 0.3 + i * 0.2;
        modelMat[13] = sinAng * 0.3 + i * 0.2;
        
        ShaderProgram.SetUniformMat44( progDraw, "u_modelViewMat44", modelMat );
        var color = col[i];
        color.push( alpha );
        ShaderProgram.SetUniform4f( progDraw, "u_color", color );
        gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inx.len, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    }
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.pos ); 
}

var startTime;
function Fract( val ) { 
    return val - Math.trunc( val );
}
function CalcAng( currentTime, intervall ) {
    return Fract( (currentTime - startTime) / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
}
function CalcMove( currentTime, intervall, range ) {
    var pos = self.Fract( (currentTime - startTime) / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0
    var pos = pos < 1.0 ? pos : (2.0-pos)
    return range[0] + (range[1] - range[0]) * pos;
}    

var mousePos = [-1, -1];
var gl;
var prog;
var bufObj = {};
function cameraStart() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById( "camera-canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;
    var vp = [canvas.width, canvas.height];

    progBack = ShaderProgram.Create( 
      [ { source : back_vert, stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : back_frag, stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
      ],
      [ "u_projectionMat44", "u_modelViewMat44"] );
    progBack.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progBack, "inPos" );
    if ( progBack == 0 )
        return;

    progDraw = ShaderProgram.Create( 
      [ { source : draw_vert, stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : draw_frag, stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
      ],
      [ "u_projectionMat44", "u_modelViewMat44", "u_color", "u_alpha", "u_vp"] );
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw, "inPos" );
    if ( progDraw == 0 )
        return;

    var pos = [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ];
    var inx = [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ];
    bufObj.pos = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.pos );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( pos ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufObj.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    bufObj.inx.len = inx.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( inx ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    startTime = Date.now();
    setInterval(drawScene, 50);
}

</script>

<body onload="cameraStart();">
    <div style="margin-left: 260px;">
        <div style="float: right; width: 100%; background-color: #CCF;">
            <form name="inputs">
                <table>
                    <tr> <td> alpha </td> 
                         <td> <input type="range" id="alpha" min="0" max="100" value="50"/></td> </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; width: 260px; margin-left: -260px;">
            <canvas id="camera-canvas" style="border: none;" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I've accepted this, because the blending parameters fit my case best. But for future readers, the premultiplied alpha mentioned in [gman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45074112/1314762) is also necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Canvas requires pre-multiplied alpha unless you specifically request otherwise so problem #1 is your blend function should be

```
  blend: {
    enable: true,
    func: {
      srcRGB: 'one',
      srcAlpha: 'one',
      dstRGB: 'one minus src alpha',
      dstAlpha: 'one minus src alpha',
    },
  },
```

You also need to return premultiplied values from your shader

```
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, alpha);
  gl_FragColor.rgb *= gl_FragColor.a;   // premultiply by alpha
}
```

The other problem is you have the depth test on. The default depth function is `LESS`. That means new pixels will not be drawn unless their Z value is LESS than existing Z values. Since all of your circles are drawn at the same depth no new circle will get drawn anywhere a previous circle was drawn.

The easiest fix is to turn off the depth test

```
  depth: {enable: false},
```

Result:

[image]

As for why premultiplied alpha see

https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre

Comment: Upvoted, but I have accepted the other answer; both gave helpful solutions. Thank you!